# Transformar labels de uma CheckBoxList em strings

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um `checkboxlist` com alguns itens e o nome deles são os diretórios para eu poder salvar o arquivo. Gostaria de saber como eu pego o nome de cada `label` selecionado do `checkboxlist` e transformá-lo em uma *string*. Gostaria de saber uma maneira para que ele salvasse vários arquivos de vez, que são os que estão na `checkboxlist`.

```
private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsMCI clsmci = new clsMCI();
    string ArtistaDoAlbum;
    string Artista;
    TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(aqui onde gostaria que o nome da label selecionada estivesse);
    tagFile.Tag.Title = tx_titulo.Text;
    tagFile.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue alguns exemplos de como capturar o texto de um CheckBoxList

```
string ex1 = chkLista.SelectedItem.Text;
string ex2 = chkLista.Items[0].Text;
```

Para salvar um registro para cada item acredito que a melhor maneira é você fazer um foreach, caso tenha entendido errado favor detalhar melhor o problema.

**OBS**: chkLista = ID DO SEU OBJETO

Comment: eu tentei usar a classe ListItem, só que eu não conseguir adicionar esse classe ao visual studio.